# RabbitMQ localhost management failing to launch with port 5672 errors in the log file

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, messagebroker, rabbitmq-exchange

I have installed RabbitMQ 3.11.2 and Erlang version 25.1.1 on Windows 10 machine.

I am very new to RabbitMQ, and I am unable to launch RabbitMQ management portal. I enabled the RabbitMQ management plugin as well.

Searched the internet with all sorts of suggestions on Stack Overflow, Google Groups, and other forums and all of them failed.

In the log files I find a lot of errors like below.

```
2022-11-07 11:50:09.594000+10:00 [error] <0.697.0> **Failed to start TCP listener [::]:5672**, error: {{shutdown,
2022-11-07 11:50:09.594000+10:00 [error] <0.697.0>                                                  {failed_to_start_child,
2022-11-07 11:50:09.594000+10:00 [error] <0.697.0>                                                   {ranch_embedded_sup,
2022-11-07 11:50:09.594000+10:00 [error] <0.697.0>                                                    {acceptor,
2022-11-07 11:50:09.594000+10:00 [error] <0.697.0>                                                     {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
2022-11-07 11:50:09.594000+10:00 [error] <0.697.0>                                                     5672}},
2022-11-07 11:50:09.594000+10:00 [error] <0.697.0>                                                   {shutdown,
2022-11-07 11:50:09.594000+10:00 [error] <0.697.0>                                                    {failed_to_start_child,
2022-11-07 11:50:09.594000+10:00 [error] <0.697.0>                                                     {ranch_listener_sup,
2022-11-07 11:50:09.594000+10:00 [error] <0.697.0>                                                      {acceptor,
2022-11-07 11:50:09.594000+10:00 [error] <0.697.0>                                                       {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
2022-11-07 11:50:09.594000+10:00 [error] <0.697.0>                                                       5672}},
2022-11-07 11:50:09.594000+10:00 [error] <0.697.0>                                                     {shutdown,
2022-11-07 11:50:09.594000+10:00 [error] <0.697.0>                                                      {failed_to_start_child,

2022-11-07 11:50:09.594000+10:00 [error] <0.704.0> **Failed to start Ranch listener {acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},5672**} in ranch_tcp:listen(#{connection_type => supervisor,handshake_timeout => 5000,max_connections => infinity,num_acceptors => 10,num_conns_sups => 1,socket_opts => [{cacerts,'...'},{key,'...'},{cert,'...'},{ip,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}},{port,5672},inet6,{backlog,128},{nodelay,true},{linger,{true,0}},{exit_on_close,false}]}) for reason eacces (permission denied)

=erl_crash_dump:0.5
Mon Nov  7 12:50:21 2022
Slogan: init terminating in do_boot **({error,{could_not_start_listener,::,5672,**{{shutdown,{_}},{child,undefined,rabbit_tcp_listener_sup_:::5672,{
```

I have diabled McAfee firewall, I have added port 5672 to McAfee firewall, reinstalled the RabbitMQ and Erlang apps at least 10 times, opened the port 5672 in windows firewall security, tried on docker images as well but my 3 days efforts failed to start it.

I have attached RabbitMQ and Erlang log files in here, please provide your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

the error is clear:

```
exception exit: {listen_error,{acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},5672},eacces}
```

From Erlang documentation:
https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html

```
eacces
Missing search or write permissions for the parent directories of Dir.
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause was another process using TCP port 5672 -

https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users/c/oPe1pU4IeNo

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/discussions/6348#discussioncomment-4077019